# Checking for existence of a value in the dataframe doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Look at the code below. I have a df and in the first method i simple check for the existence of 'Ankit' in the entire dataframe and this works but the second method does'nt. why?

```
import pandas as pd

# dictionary with list object in values
details = {
'Name' : ['Ankit', 'Aishwarya', 'Shaurya',
          'Shivangi', 'Priya', 'Swapnil'],
'Age' : [23, 21, 22, 21, 24, 25],
'University' : ['BHU', 'JNU', 'DU', 'BHU', 'Geu', 'Geu'],}
# creating a Dataframe object
df = pd.DataFrame(details, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'University'],
              index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])

print("Dataframe: \n\n", df)

# check 'Ankit' exist in dataframe or not
if 'Ankit' in df.values :
    print("\nThis value exists in Dataframe")
if 'Ankit' in df['Name']:
    print("\nThis value exists in Dataframe")
else:
    print("not found")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `in` when used directly with a `DataFrame[column_name]` is equivalent when using it with `DataFrame.index`, it is to check if a value exists in it's **`index`**

So for example, since `a` is one of your indexes:

```
'a' in df['Name']
```

Will return `True`, to check within its values, you need to use the `.values` attribute:

```
'Ankit' in df['Name'].values
```

Will return `True`.

Comment: Then prove me wrong @athing

Comment: I don't need a `Series`, I can use `.index` too to check for it, without specifying `.columns` or a specific column, but I will edit it and clarify it. @athing

Comment: no no, you say "The behavior of in when used directly with a DataFrame is to check if a value exists in it's index" it is not correct. Correct version "The behavior of in when used directly with a DataFrame is to check if a value exists in it's Columns" Or change it to "The behavior of in when used directly with a Series is to check if a value exists in it's index" to make it context related

Comment: @athing Ok, I clarified my meaning.